# Lodash Javascript Return Elements Based Of Off Unique Property Values

Tags: javascript, lodash

I'm trying to utilize lodash but cannot find a javascript function that will take this:

```
[
{item: {id: 1}, 'name': 'hi'},
{item: {id: 2}, 'name': 'hey'},
{item: {id: 1}, 'name': 'hello'}
];
```

and turn it into

```
[
{item: {id: 1}, 'name': 'hi'},
{item: {id: 2}, 'name': 'hey'}
];
```

So far I have in javascript this:

```
var mainThings = [
        {item: {id: 1}, 'name': 'hi'},
        {item: {id: 2}, 'name': 'hey'},
        {item: {id: 1}, 'name': 'hello'}
        ];

uniqueMainsFunc = function() {
    var ids = [],
        mains = [];

    _.forEach(mainThings, function(thing) {
        if (ids.indexOf(thing.item.id) === -1) {
            ids.push(thing.item.id);
            mains.push(thing);
        }
    });
    return uniqueMains;
};
```

In this scenario uniqueMains would only contain:

```
[
{item: {id: 1}, 'name': 'hi'},
{item: {id: 2}, 'name': 'hey'}
]
```

Is there a lodash function that can better handle this?
After the .forEach I tried to use !_.some(uniqueNestedIds, thing.item.id) and it did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[uniqBy](https://lodash.com/docs#uniqBy) method can solve your problem

```
var mainThings = [
    { item: { id: 1 }, 'name': 'hi' },
    { item: { id: 2 }, 'name': 'hey' },
    { item: { id: 1 }, 'name': 'hello' }
];


var uniq = _.uniqBy(mainThings, 'item.id')

console.log(uniq);
```

Result:

```
[ { item: { id: 1 }, name: 'hi' },
  { item: { id: 2 }, name: 'hey' } ]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`_.uniqBy`](https://lodash.com/docs#uniqBy) for this:

```
_.uniqBy(mainThings, function(item) {
    return item.item.id;
});
```

See [this Plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/7acIwUkttlsh5QWYBu0k).